# How to edit Wordpress register page error codes?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am trying to find a way to edit the error codes that the wordpress register page throws. For example:

> ERROR: Please enter a username.
>
> ERROR: The email address isn’t correct.

Where are these stored so I can change them?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a filter for this in `wp-login.php`. But don't touch WordPress core files, filter and action hooks are in place so you can modify WP behavior without editing the core.

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'registration_errors_so_16002591' );

function registration_errors_so_16002591( $errors )
{
    if( isset( $errors->errors['invalid_email'] ) ) {
        $errors->errors['invalid_email'][0] = '<strong>bad</strong> email';
    }
    if( isset( $errors->errors['username_exists'] ) ) {
        $errors->errors['username_exists'][0] = 'nick <strong>picken</strong>';
    }
    // Other errors
    // ['empty_email']
    // ['empty_username']

    return $errors;
}
```

<sub>*Related Q&A: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)*</sub>